# Using ResumeAfter in proactive bot dialog

Tags: botframework

I have a couple of questions about the example that shows how to start a proactive dialog:

```
            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
            {
                var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
                await botData.LoadAsync(token);

                var task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();
                var interruption = dialog.Void<T, IMessageActivity>();

                task.Call(interruption, null);

                await task.PollAsync(token);
                await botData.FlushAsync(token);
            }
```

1. What is the point of calling dialog.Void?
2. How can I use a ResumeAfter? If i add a ResumeAfter handler and await the result i get an error indicating it was expecting Call and got Poll
3. Is this code supposed to block until the dialog is complete? Because it does not

How can I push a proactive dialog and await its result?

Comment: Why do you want to get the result in the class that launches the proactive dialog? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a Skype calling bot, as part of the spoken conversation the user has the option to upload photos so i invoke a dialog which then prompts for attachments, i want my calling bot to wait until files are uploaded and get the result of the dialog to then confirm with the user that the attachments have been received. At the moment i am getting the user to enter # on the keypad when done but want to skip this step if possible.